# php Script does not run when reading sql script

Tags: php, mysql

I habe problems with my php script. The Script reads data from a mysqli database an then saves it into an array for later use. The script did work well until I wanted to insert some more sql statements to keep my mysli table, where I get the data from, up to date.

I used the first three lines to connect to database and run the sql script. Without them everything is fine.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','mks-solution-dev');
$sqlSource = file_get_contents('Einrichtung.sql');
mysqli_multi_query($con,$sqlSource);

$categories = Category::getTopCategories();
$categories = array_values($categories);
echo json_encode($categories);

    // Here, the entries in $data are indexed by the values they also have in                  'name'
// If you want them numerically indexed, all you have to do is:
//$data = array_values($data);
//echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
//echo json_encode($data);      

class Category
{
    /**
     * The information stored in the database for each category
     */
    public $id;
    public $parent;
    public $name;
    public $vlink;      

    // The child categories
    public $children;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Get the child categories when we get this category
        $this->getChildCategories();
    }

    /**
     * Get the child categories
     * @return array
     */
    public function getChildCategories()
    {
        if ($this->children) {
            return $this->children;
        }
        return $this->children = self::getCategories("parent = {$this->id}");
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * The top-level categories (i.e. no parent)
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getTopCategories()
    {
        return self::getCategories('parent = 0');
    }

    /**
     * Get categories from the database.
     * @param string $where Conditions for the returned rows to meet
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getCategories($where = '')
    {
        if ($where) $where = " WHERE $where";
        $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','mks-solution-dev');
        mysqli_set_charset($conn,"UTF8"); 


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mdl_praktikum$where";         
        print $sql;         

        $result =mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        print $result;

        $categories = array();
        while ($category = mysqli_fetch_object($result, 'Category'))
           {
        $vlink = array('vlink' => $category->vlink);
        unset($category->vlink);
        $category->data = $vlink;
        $categories[] = $category;
       }

        mysqli_free_result($sqlSource);
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        return $categories;
    }
}
?>
```

Here you see the result with the integrated sql script:

```
SELECT * FROM mdl_praktikum WHERE parent = 0[]
```

and some of it without:

```
SELECT * FROM mdl_praktikum WHERE parent = 0 

SELECT * FROM mdl_praktikum WHERE parent = 1 

SELECT * FROM mdl_praktikum WHERE parent = 2 

SELECT * FROM mdl_praktikum WHERE parent = 3 

SELECT * FROM mdl_praktikum WHERE parent = 6 
.
.
.
SELECT * FROM mdl_praktikum WHERE parent = 386 

SELECT * FROM mdl_praktikum WHERE parent = 387 

SELECT * FROM mdl_praktikum WHERE parent = 388 

[{"id":"1","parent":"0","name":"root","children":[{"id":"2","parent":"1","name":"Verschiedenes","children":[],"ref":"1","layer":"1","data":{"vlink":null}},{"id":"3","parent":"1","name":"EBSN","children":[{"id":"6","parent":"3","name":"EBSN 1415","children":[{"id":"23","parent":"6","name":"General .......
```

I think somewhere in my method getCategories somethíng went totally wrong but I am dont getting why

Comment: MySQL != SQL Server

Comment: Please do not abuse the snippet tool. It should be used for HTML/JS/CSS only.

Comment: It sounds like the SQL script is deleting the data from the table. What's in the SQL script?

Comment: Are you writing your own ORM? If so, why? You should look at [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) and 
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) before you go any farther down this road. I have a suspicion this encourages people to create gaping [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com/) since it doesn't support placeholder values.

Comment: Yes the Script deletes the Table and then creates it again and fills it with information from other tables.Overall there are 8 statements in it.

Comment: @tadman, the php is part of a moodle plugin I am coding

Comment: Yes, I can see that. You should learn from examples like those before you go and re-invent anything. I'd strongly encourage you to use one of those ORMs, they're tested, proven, and community supported.